# ログインすると[FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.]が表示されてしまいます。

Tags: firebase

FirebaseとNuxt.jsで認証付きアプリを作っています。

GoogleAuthを使用しているのですが、ログイン後にconsoleに

```
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

と表示されてしまいます。

ログイン自体はできていて、ログイン後の画面に切り替わるのですが、エラーが出てしまっているという状況です。

FirebaseのCloud Firestoreのルールは以下のように記述していますが、問題はありますでしょうか？

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /blogs/{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
```